# auto job creation in Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket

I am looking for a solution so that I can create a Jenkins job automatically.

I have 5 bitbucket repositories and all these repositories have jenkins file. I am using pipe line as code. Now I do not want to create 5 different jobs in Jenkins for all 5 repositories.

I need the logic that It should detect the change in the repository and then automatically jenkins job should be created and build happens.

Please help!

Thanks,
Tadul Shah

Answer (score 1):

You can use jenkins multi-branch functionality.

Complete setup can be found in jenkins document.

https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/multibranch/

Comment: Tadul Shah wants something like multirepo job. So repositories will be automatically added as jobs (like in Travis CI, appveyor, etc)